# Generate sql statements with flyway placeholders

Tags: java, jooq, flyway, property-placeholder

I trying to save some sql insert statements to files to use them for testing.
I would like to use [flyway placeholders](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/placeholders) for that but I'm not able to find any.

Some example in Java:

```
var sqlTXT = sql.insertInto(table("TBLNAME"))
     .set(field("strCol"), field("strVal").toString())
     .set(field("placeHolderCol"), field(inline("${flyway:user}")))
     .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

This will produce SQL string like this one:

```
insert into TBLNAME (strCol, placeHolderCol) values ('strVal', '${flyway:user}')
```

and I'm looking for something like this

```
insert into TBLNAME (strCol, placeHolderCol) values ('strVal', ${flyway:user})
```

So flyway can substitute `${flyway:user}` and insert user name.

Is there any way to render sql like this or will I have to do it "manually"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway's placeholders are no different from any other "vendor specific" SQL syntax, which isn't supported out of the box by jOOQ, so [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) has the answer.

Just use

```java
field("${flyway:user}")
```

Don't use [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline(java.lang.String)), which is used for creating ["inline values"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/) (e.g. a string literal).